# No results from SQLite when trying to select by PrimaryKey using sqlite-net

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, primary-key, sqlite-net

For this example, I've defined the following class, which is saved inside an SQLite database:

```
[SQLite.AutoIncrement, SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Indexed]
public int ID { get; set; }
[SQLite.Indexed]
public string ImageName { get; set; }
```

I'm using the insert command supplied with sqlite-net, and it works:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection CurrentConnection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("DB");
int result = await CurrentConnection.InsertAsync(this);
```

Afterwards, I'm trying to select data from the SQLite DB.

```
List<Image> result = new List<Image>();
if (ImageName != null)
{
    query = CurrentConnection.Table<Image>().Where(i => i.ImageName == ImageName);
    result = await query.ToListAsync();
}
if (ID != null && ID > 0)
{
    query = CurrentConnection.Table<Image>().Where(i => i.ID == ID);
    result = await query.ToListAsync();
}
if (result.Count > 0)
{
    LoadFromResult(result[0]);
    return;
}
```

When selecting by ImageName, all works well and I get the results I need. However, when trying to select by ID, no results are selected.

I know the image with the given ID exists since I've just inserted it and checked the ID afterwards, but for some reason this just does not work.

Am I completely blind and missed a small letter here? Has anyone used SQLite-net to try and select by Primary key?

//Edit

Also tried this, which did not work:

```
var query1 = await CurrentConnection.QueryAsync<Image>("select * from Image where ID = ?", ID);
if (query1.Count > 0)
{
    LoadFromResult(query1[0]);
    return;
}
```

//edit 2

I've got a bit of a hunch on this - when I insert the image, the ID does get set to some ID, however when I select all the images in the DB, all of them have an ID of 0.

Any idea on why this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be with AutoIncrement attribute for your class.
Try removing the AutoIncrement attribute and see, if you can find the image by id.

I think what's happening is that the AutoIncrement attribute is setting the Id, overriding the id you create.

For Example

Let's say you create an instance of your MyImage with:

MyImage i = new MyImage() { Id=**5**,
  ImageName="imageName"}

When you run,CurrentConnection.InsertAsync(i) (on an empty table), the entry inserted to the database has ID **1**, not **5**.

Hope that helped

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, However I do not set the ID manually - I let the Insert row do that for me. After I insert, the ID property changes to the ID that SQLite gave it. That's how I know I'm not overwriting the entry again. Moreover, if I select by ImageName, I get the entry I want.

Comment: I created a simple example following your class and syntax [SampleLink](https://gist.github.com/4300253). I was able to succesfully retrieve the iamge by its Id and Name.
Not sure it matters, but I I used a console project with sqlite version (3071500) and sqlite-net(1.0.5).

Comment: Versions could have an affect, as well as the fact that I'm using a Windows 8 application. I'll check if I have the same versions

Comment: I've got a bit of a hunch on this - when I insert the image, the ID does get set to some ID, however when I select all the images in the DB, all of them have an ID of 0.